# Docker port forwarding stops working after stopping container and restarting it?

Tags: docker

Docker (v20.10.17, install following [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/)) port forwarding stops working after stopping container and restarting it? (Requires full reinstall to get working again).

Creating postgres docker container in Ubuntu 18.04 like...

```bash
docker run -it \
  -e POSTGRES_USER="root" \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="root" \
  -e POSTGRES_DB="ny_taxi" \
  -v /my/absolute/path/to/my/local/folder/ny_taxi_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw \
  -p 5432:5432 \
  postgres:13
```

...but can't connect when using `psql`

```
➜  ~ psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U root -W
Password for user root: 
psql: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

or using `pgadmin4` from my local desktop or changing "localhost" to the value "0.0.0.0"

**I find that after doing a fresh install of docker following the info here ( https://askubuntu.com/a/1021506/760862 ) then re-running the `sudo apt-get install` command for the docker packages,...**

```bash
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
```

**...I was able to `psql` into the container's DB, but only for the first time of running that container**. Eg. after ctl+C'ing the container, re-running the exact same `docker run` command, I could no longer `psql` into the DB (getting the same "*psql: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly*" error I've been seeing).

My linux docker group info looks like:

```
➜ cat /etc/group | grep docker
docker:x:999:myusername
```

I see no local postgres service running:

```
➜  ~ systemctl status postgresql
Unit postgresql.service could not be found.
➜  ~ service postgresql status
Unit postgresql.service could not be found.
```

and this is the only thing that appears to be using the specified port:

```
➜ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
.
.
.
docker-pr  5125            root    4u  IPv4 3785093      0t0  TCP *:5432 (LISTEN)
docker-pr  5132            root    4u  IPv6 3778439      0t0  TCP *:5432 (LISTEN)
➜
➜
➜
➜ sudo netstat -tulpen | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          4897282    15384/docker-proxy  
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          4897287    15391/docker-proxy
```

This is also the only docker container I have running and the image was just downloaded today:

```
➜ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE         COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                                       NAMES
033699b59c10   postgres:13   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   lucid_mcclintock
```

The logged output I see from the docker container is

```
➜ docker container logs lucid_mcclintock

PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

2022-08-16 20:51:39.219 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.8 (Debian 13.8-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2022-08-16 20:51:39.219 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2022-08-16 20:51:39.219 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2022-08-16 20:51:39.231 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-08-16 20:51:39.249 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-08-16 20:51:34 UTC
2022-08-16 20:51:39.261 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

(I'm pretty sure the *"database system was shut down at"* log message is just from the fact that I `ctl+C`ed out of the container the previously).
This log output for the DB container does not change even when trying to `psql` connect using a wrong username or password (eg. having some message about a failed login attempt) -- thus making me suspect some kind of port forwarding issue with docker.

IDK how much this helps (b/c not much experience with docker), but the only container I see on the docker Bridge network (via `docker network inspect bridge`) is the container name of the one running the DB (ie. no hidden container also using the network).

I also see:

```bash
➜ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE         COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                                       NAMES
033699b59c10   postgres:13   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago   Up 4 hours   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   lucid_mcclintock
➜ docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' 033699b59c10  
172.17.0.2
```

This issue appears to affect all port forwarding with docker containers on my computer. Eg. I also have issues now doing a test like like

```bash
➜ docker run -p 9999:80 httpd
```

While in a separate terminal running:

```bash
➜ curl localhost:9999
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

My docker version is

```bash
➜ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.17
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.17.11
 Git commit:        100c701
 Built:             Mon Jun  6 23:02:56 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true
```

Checking the IPTables output (in response to comments (I don't really understand any implications of the output)), I see:

```bash
➜ sudo iptables --list 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:postgresql

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

This seems really weird, but I have little experience with docker or networking. Does anyone have any debugging suggestions, more diagnostics that should be added here, or know what could be going wrong?

Comment: you can see all port-mappings of your system using `netstat -tulpen`

Comment: docker uses iptables, you can use `iptables -L` to inspect port mappings and firewall.

Comment: I had the same issue which I solved removing the volume mapping as I only needed it for a local test. Could you do a test running the same test without a volume mapping?

Comment: @Khanzadeh_AH Added my `iptables` output to post (note that I don't work with networking stuff, so I don't really understand any implications of what I'm seeing there).

Comment: @Andrea Unfortunately that didn't work (still could not `psql` into the container DB). Do you remember what the exact issue was in your case for that? Any SO (or other) reference to that issue anywhere online (just so I can see if there is any useful debugging steps I could try)?